# Problem with download link

Tags: java, jsp

I want to insert in a web page a download link.

Here's the code:

```
<li>über <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/handyprogramm/TeamViewer_Setup.exe">diesen Link</a> per Download auf Ihren PC und anschließendem Überspielen auf Ihr Handy (z.B. per Datenkabel, Speicherkarten-Adapter, Bluetooth, WLAN, o.ä.).</li>
```

When I click on the link, I get an error that says: "The file could not be found".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: point the mouse on the link in your page, check the generated URL. you may find whats wrong with generated URL.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that either the URL is wrong or that the file is actually not there where you expect it is. As hinted in the comment, you'd like to verify if the URL in the generated HTML output is correct. Noted should be that URL's are case sensitive in case of JSP/Servlet containers.

To test the one and other (and to exclude JSP from being suspect), best is start trying downloading the file manually by entering its URL manually in the browser address bar. If you succeeds, then just "translate" the particular URL into the JSP page that way so that it ends up being correct in the generated HTML output.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ...

I have an EXE file (TeamViewer_Setup.exe) in my computer and then copied into the project under the folder "mobile tv" extension. But with the path "$ () pageContext.request.contextPath / mobile tv / TeamViewer_Setup.exe" I can not access the EXE file. I always get the same error message ("The file could not be found").

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I already answered that. Did you try downloading it manually? Did you check if the generated HTML output is correct?